# I wish to add a progress listener or feedback for this submit function to let the user know when the task is complete

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui

I wish to use  Or any Material-UI feedback component to capture the submit progress of the form

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (eventImage) {
        const uploadImage = storage.ref(`EventImages/${values.eventName}`)
        uploadImage.put(eventImage).then(() => {
            storage.ref('EventImages').child(values.eventName).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                dbref.add({
                    eventName: values.eventName,
                    eventVenue: values.eventVenue,
                    eventAddress: values.eventAddress,
                    eventCategory: values.eventCategory,
                    eventOrganizer: values.eventOrganizer,
                    eventPhone: values.eventPhone,
                    eventEmail: values.eventEmail,
                    eventDetails: values.eventDetails,
                    eventDate: selectedDate.toDateString(),
                    eventTime: selectedDate.toLocaleTimeString(),
                    eventImgUrl: url
                }).then((docRef) => {
                    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                    setValues("");
                    setImg("");
                    setImgName("");
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                });
            })
        })

    }
    }
```

I wish to use any Material-UI feedback component to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

Typically a progress bar is used in such situations, so that the user knows how much of the task is completed/remains.

IMO showing a percentage completed and/or time remaining is helpful to. (time is a bit harder to implement)

Material UI Progress Bar : https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#linear-buffer

This might help?

They have an example attached with source code as well. Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Where should i attach the progress?